# How to properly redirect Python script output to file?

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am trying to run a script remotely on a server and I intend to use something along the following lines:
`nohup ./script.py > runtime.out 2> runtime.err &` and monitor the script's progress with `tail -f runtiime.out`. The problem I am having is that the redirect doesn't seem to work as expected. For the purposes of my problem my problem can be reproduced as described below:

script.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
if __name__=='__main__':
    for i in range(1000):
        print("hi")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Then in shell run `./print.py > a.out &`. This will give the PID of the proccess and will exit as expected. However `a.out` is empty despite the program running. Also if i do `./print.py > a.out`  without the '&' the `a.out` file remains empty until I Ctrl-C the command. Then it displays all expected output until the termination of the script.

I thought the ">" redirected continuously the stdout and stderr and not only at command completion.

Comment: @JervenClark Why is that? There's no need to open the file inside of Python. stdout can be flushed or be made unbuffered as two of the answers show.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thank you for this. I didn't know earlier you could flush using print. I only know you could do in a file.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way to do that is just by using `-u` flag of the `python` command. It should look like that:

```
nohup python3 -u script.py > runtime.out 2> runtime.err &
```

According to the `python3 --help`:

> -u     : force the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered;
> this option has no effect on stdin; also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x

Answer (score 3):

Using `print("hi", flush=True)` will keep forcing the stream to flush contents, so it will continuously update the output file. I don't have enough information about your program to suggest alternatives, but I would look for a better method if possible.